Find a solution satisfying a $\partial\bar{\partial}$ equation on the punctured disc
Denote by $\mathbb D$ (resp. $\mathbb D^*$) the open disc (resp. the punctured disc) in $\mathbb C$. Let $u$ be a smooth function over the total disc $\mathbb D$ (which is not harmonic usually). I am interested in the following question:
For the fixed $u$ and a fixed rational number $q\in (0,1)$, can we always find some solution $h$ which  is smooth over $\mathbb D$ such that the following  equation holds
over $\mathbb D^*$?
$$\partial\bar{\partial}u=\partial\bar{\partial}h+ q \frac{dz}{z}\wedge \bar\partial h.$$
I have tried some candidates, such as let $u=\frac{h}{z}$ or something, but all are lost. If this equation cannot be solved always, I wonder that  can we give some counterexamples?
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot.
EDIT
At the beginning, I asked $h$ to be holomorphic over the punctured disc is too much (and Didier's answer for this assumption is great.

(-1) Why did you delete and repost your old question?

Why he can not delete his old post? Did he made serious mistake that worth downvoting 5 times?

@yili the mods have deleted the subsequent conversation which prompted the downvotes. There is no need to witch hunt this user further so long as they learned from their mistakes.

Let us consider the map
$$
\begin{array}{rccc}
F \colon & \mathcal{C}^2(\mathbb{D}^*) & \longrightarrow & \mathcal{C}^0(\mathbb{D}^*) \\
& h & \longmapsto & \partial\bar\partial h + \frac{dz}{z}\wedge \bar\partial h
\end{array}
$$
which is well defined (identifying $2$-forms with functions).
Your question is: given some $u \in \mathcal{C}^2(\mathbb D)$, does there exist $h \in \mathcal{H}(\mathbb{D}^*) \subset \mathcal{C}^2(\mathbb D^*)$ which is meromorphic around $0$ and with $F(h) = \partial\bar\partial u$?
The thing is that the restriction of $F$ to $\mathcal{H}(\mathbb D^*)$, the holomorphic functions, is the zero function.
Hence, an obvious obstruction to your problem is the non-harmonicity of $u$.

I see, I have asked too much for h. Please see my edits

@Invariance This is now a totally different question. Changing the core of the question is considered as bad practice on MSE, especially when someone already answered the original question (my answer now seems completely out of the scope!). It is considered as a better option to accept the answer and post a second question that more accurately fits your needs.

@Invariance Note that I am not asking for you to accept my answer. If you really want to keep it as it is, I'll either delete or edit my answer to notify the change in the question

Thanks Didier, I will accept it and reask a question later.
